# Does anyone know a good system for building a city?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, tool-recommendation, modern, geist-the-sin-eaters

We're beginning a **Geist** game and we talked about how interesting it would be to build a city together as a group so we really felt like it was our home town.

I've heard *Damnation City* is good, but also that it's primarily focused on VtR and how to control a city as a vampire. It doesn't really matter if it fits well with White Wolf — we can kit-bash it — but really we're looking for something that can help us do it, preferably something that would tell us the good, the bad, and give a few plot hook ideas for other things being brought into the city.

Comment: Are you looking for sourcebook suggestions, or general advice for city building?

Comment: My go-to system for collaboratively building any setting stuff is playing a session of [Microscope](http://www.lamemage.com/). It's not specific to city-building (hence a comment-not-answer), but could do it handily. Sounds like a short session would give you plenty to work with.

Comment: I won't put it as an answer because it contradicts the OP, but *Damnation City* isn't so Vampire-focused that it's not a great resource for what you want.

Comment: General advice, actually.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You *must* check out the city creation in the Dresden Files RPG. It is specifically designed for group collaboration. It takes your group step-by-step through points of interest, supernatural influence, key players, etc. You decide along the way why things are important and what makes them cool.

The rules don't really care about the granularity of demographic statistics or street layout. Which is good, because your game doesn't really need those. It *does* produce a story-rich setting in which to base your game.

You can find them starting on page 24 of *Dresden Files RPG: Volume 1 - Your Story*.

Comment: As a bonus, it's a good genre match.

Comment: +1 It also has a really good set of advise on making RPG representations of real cities.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie  Which book has this material in it?

Comment: @KieranMullen Added a book and page number. This was less ambiguous back in 2011, but the answer really should have been explicit to begin with. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### [GURPS City Stats](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/75501/gurps-city-stats)

I haven't gotten my hands on this yet, but since I'm a [realm-management](/questions/tagged/realm-management) fiend, it's on my list. Here's what the publisher has to say:

> Since the dawn of history, people have come to cities – to visit, to pass through, to stay. And bustling streets provide opportunities for adventure.
>
> GURPS City Stats offers cohesive rules to define a city’s impact on adventurers. A new stat block provides a compact way to write up a city, just like a character, vehicle, or planet. Guidelines for using urban regions in your campaign suggest how to turn them into exciting encounters or challenging places to live.
>
> City Stats also includes stats, descriptions, notable residents, and campaign options for four sample locations suited to different types of campaigns: Athens (historical), Tredroy (fantasy/GURPS Banestorm), San Francisco (modern), and Pavonis Portal (science fiction).

Comment: This supplement is primarly about how to stat a city in GURPS terms. It useful, but mostly if you're running a GURPS game and is closer to guidelines than a fully featured design system per see.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any systems/sourcebooks that do this.

However, were I the storyteller, I'd do the following:

- Buy in from players.  I've found that if the players don't care about adding to the game world (as opposed from playing in the world), then you won't get anything from them (at least not anything useful).
- Come up with the general statistics.  Population, ethnicity (in percentages), relative level of wealth, etc.  You want to know that people are wealthy
- Decide how many kinds of "monsters" the city will have.  Will it be a Geist only town?  Are there Vampires?  Werewolves?  Mages?  Aliens?  Rabid Soccer Hooligans?  How many (roughly) should each population be?
- Now ask the players to fill in the details:
- What's the major industry(ies)?
- What's the name of the major employer(s)?
- Maybe give the players some sort of XP bonus for each detail that they offer to be filled in.

Answer (score 2):

There's also *Block By Bloody Block* which is the sourcebook for building cities/neighborhoods for Hunter: The Vigil.  It's smaller then *Damnation City* but provides various suggestions for city layout and integrates supernatural threats from other lines if I remember right.  I'll also echo the comment to not discount *Damnation City* as it's a very impressive book for city building!

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, if you're looking for city layout, the [Cartographers' Guild](http://www.cartographersguild.com) has several tutorials on making city maps. [This one](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?1150-Award-Winner-A-medieval-town-map-tutorial-in-Photoshop), for example.